# tinyMCE editor gives encoded result for multilingual character

Tags: php, html, character-encoding, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE editor to update the CMS content, it's working fine in English language, but if i enter japanese(`テスト=>test`) language and submit(jQuery+Ajax) it's giving the output as `%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8`.

I am getting the editor content value as

`escape($.trim(tinyMCE.get('textarea_content').getContent()));`

I used entity encoding in tinyMCE initialization as

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        entity_encoding : "raw"
});
```

but no luck.

Comment: `%u30C6%u30B9%u30C8` which is what should be expected?

Comment: i expected the same as i entered `テスト`

Comment: if i remove escape i cant update HTML content, it says `Disallowed Key Characters`.

Comment: how do you store and retrieve your editor content?

Comment: @Thariama am storing the content in mysql database with the `utf8_general_ci` collation  and `text` datatype

Answer (score 0):

It should work to replace `%u` with `\u` before you init your editor.

```
var content = $('textarea_content').html().replace('/\\%u/gi','\u');
$('textarea_content').html(content);

tinymce.execCommand('mceAddControl', false, 'textarea_content');
```